# React Native: iOS dictation unable to clear text input

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I have a pretty basic TextInput + Button combination in a React Native app used to write and send messages, like so:

```
<TextInput
    type="text"
    ref={input => {
       this.inputRef = input;
    }}
    style={styles.userInput}
    name="userInput"
    autoCorrect={false}
    placeholder="Type something..."
    autoFocus={false}
    autoComplete="off"
    onChangeText={this.watchInput}
    returnKeyType="done"
/>

<Button
    disabled={!this.state.isValidInput}
    style={styles.sendButton}
    title="Send"
    textStyle={{fontSize: 12}}
    onPress={this.handleSubmit}
    accessibilityLabel="Press this button to send your message"
/>
```

When the Button is pressed, I use a handleSubmit function to handle the message sending and reseting of the input field, like this:

```
handleSubmit = async () => {
   const message = this.state.input; // get input from state

   Keyboard.dismiss() // hide keyboard
   this.inputRef.clear(); // clear TextInput
   this.setState({ input: '' }); // reset input state
   this.setState({ isValidInput: false }); // reset input state
   this.stretchInputField()
   var r = await this.props.myAwesomeSendMessageFunction() // send message
 }
```

This works just fine when using the actual Button to do the sending, but if I were to use the dictation in iOS keyboard, it does send the message when I finish speaking, but the input field is not cleared, so I'm left with the same input in the field that was already sent by the handler.

Any ideas why it's working like that with the dictation and how to get it to clear the input field as well when sending?

React Native version 0.57.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you bind your value in your text input??

Try to bind your input like value ={this.state.input} in your text input